# What does the operationTimeout in ISessionClient.AcceptMessageSessionAsync actually do?

Tags: c#, azure, azureservicebus, azure-servicebus-queues

**Context**: I have some code that's creating a message session for a particular session, using
`ISessionClient.Task<IMessageSession> AcceptMessageSessionAsync(string sessionId, TimeSpan operationTimeout);`

**Question**: What does the operationTimeout in AcceptMessageSessionAsync do? I tried setting it to one minute but, after a minute, nothing happened. Does this timeout just set a property that I need to check myself? Shouldn't a SessionLockLostException fire?

**Code Sample**:

```
var session = await sessionClient.AcceptMessageSessionAsync(0, TimeSpan.FromMinutes(1));
var gotSession = true;

if (gotSession)
{
    while (!session.IsClosedOrClosing)
    {
        try
        {
            Message message = await session.ReceiveAsync(TimeSpan.FromMinutes(2));
            if (message != null)
            {
                await session.CompleteAsync(message.SystemProperties.LockToken);
            }
            else
            {
                await session.CloseAsync();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OperationTimeout in AcceptMessageSessionAsync is the amount of time for which the call should wait for to fetch the next session.

You can find the Here is the complete implementation of the AcceptMessageSessionAsync method

```js
 /// <summary>
        /// Gets a particular session object identified by <paramref name="sessionId"/> that can be used to receive messages for that sessionId.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="sessionId">The sessionId present in all its messages.</param>
        /// <param name="operationTimeout">Amount of time for which the call should wait to fetch the next session.</param>
        /// <remarks>All plugins registered on <see cref="SessionClient"/> will be applied to each <see cref="MessageSession"/> that is accepted.
        /// Individual sessions can further register additional plugins.</remarks>
        public async Task<IMessageSession> AcceptMessageSessionAsync(string sessionId, TimeSpan operationTimeout)
        {
            this.ThrowIfClosed();

            MessagingEventSource.Log.AmqpSessionClientAcceptMessageSessionStart(
                this.ClientId,
                this.EntityPath,
                this.ReceiveMode,
                this.PrefetchCount,
                sessionId);

            bool isDiagnosticSourceEnabled = ServiceBusDiagnosticSource.IsEnabled();
            Activity activity = isDiagnosticSourceEnabled ? this.diagnosticSource.AcceptMessageSessionStart(sessionId) : null;
            Task acceptMessageSessionTask = null;

            var session = new MessageSession(
                this.EntityPath,
                this.EntityType,
                this.ReceiveMode,
                this.ServiceBusConnection,
                this.CbsTokenProvider,
                this.RetryPolicy,
                this.PrefetchCount,
                sessionId,
                true);

            try
            {
                acceptMessageSessionTask = this.RetryPolicy.RunOperation(
                    () => session.GetSessionReceiverLinkAsync(operationTimeout),
                    operationTimeout);
                await acceptMessageSessionTask.ConfigureAwait(false);
            }
            catch (Exception exception)
            {
                if (isDiagnosticSourceEnabled)
                {
                    this.diagnosticSource.ReportException(exception);
                }

                MessagingEventSource.Log.AmqpSessionClientAcceptMessageSessionException(
                    this.ClientId,
                    this.EntityPath,
                    exception);

                await session.CloseAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
                throw AmqpExceptionHelper.GetClientException(exception);
            }
            finally
            {
                this.diagnosticSource.AcceptMessageSessionStop(activity, session.SessionId, acceptMessageSessionTask?.Status);
            }

            MessagingEventSource.Log.AmqpSessionClientAcceptMessageSessionStop(
                this.ClientId,
                this.EntityPath,
                session.SessionIdInternal);

            session.UpdateClientId(ClientEntity.GenerateClientId(nameof(MessageSession), $"{this.EntityPath}_{session.SessionId}"));
            // Register plugins on the message session.
            foreach (var serviceBusPlugin in this.RegisteredPlugins)
            {
                session.RegisterPlugin(serviceBusPlugin);
            }

            return session;
        }
```

You can find the complete sample in below link

https://github.com/Azure/azure-service-bus-dotnet/blob/dev/src/Microsoft.Azure.ServiceBus/SessionClient.cs

Hope it helps.